# One day difference in Converting Gregorian to Hijri date using Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, hijri

I am trying to convert Gregorian to Hijri date using Intl.DateTimeFormat, But every time it converts one day ahead. For example today is 11 Ramadan but every time it results in 12 Ramadan.

I have tried all calendar types "islamic, islamic-umalqura, islamic-civil, islamic-rgsa" I have also tried to change locale "PK, IN, AF, SA" but no difference. Is that a bug or I am doing something wrong.

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  'en-PK-u-ca-islamic', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric'
  }).format(new Date(2024, 2, 22)));  // 22 Mar 2024
```

Comment: seems to agree with `https://hamariweb.com/islam/islamic-date-today.aspx` - *Worldwide Islamic date today is 12 Ramadan 1445 in Arab countries and other parts of the world. South Asian countries, including Pakistan, India, and Bangladesh, observe the Islamic date as 11 Ramadan 1445* so I guess you're getting the worldwide date

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes bro, I am from Pakistan and today is 11 Ramadan, How to change the timezone, any idea.

Comment: nothing to do with timezone, it has to do with Worldwide vs Pakistan

Answer (score 0):

```
// just a simple example

const HijriDate = require('date-hijri');
const hijriDate = new HijriDate(Date.now());
console.log(`${hijriDate.getDate()} ${hijriDate.getMonthName()} ${hijriDate.getFullYear()}`);
```

Using a dedicated library like date-hijri will be more reliable for your conversion

Comment: Why would a library be more reliable? Do you know of bugs in implementations of *Intl.DateTimeFormat* that produce errors with Hijri calendars? [*date-hijri*](https://github.com/abdennour/hijri-date/tree/master) is at version 0.2.2 and hasn't had any maintenance in 8 years.

Comment: yes, I know that it has not been updated since long time. but open source (base) code can be updated import 'hijri-date' as stated in abdennour's page;

 const today = new HijriDate();
 const day_eid_adha = new HijriDate(1438, 12, 10); // عيد الأضحى لسنة 1438
 const dayGreg = day_eid_adha.toGregorian()  ;
 //  Fri Sep 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (AST)
//------ Convert from Gregorian to Hijri---------
 const nowGreg = new Date();
 const nowHijri = nowGreg.toHijri();

Answer (score -1):

[image: Results]

Try this

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + (currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000) + (5.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
const islamicDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-PK-u-ca-islamic', {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(currentDate);

console.log(islamicDate);
```

Comment: Bro its still showing 12 Ramadan, In Pakistan its 11 today, seems like its a timezone issue.

Comment: Have you tried running on you editor? Like not on the snippet here?

Comment: Try this and please upvote
const currentDate = new Date();
const options = { timeZone: 'Asia/Karachi', timeZoneName: 'short' }; 
const islamicDate = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-PK-u-ca-islamic', options);

console.log(islamicDate);

Comment: A good solution explains why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. I can't see any logic behind this methodology.

Comment: @MburuNjoroge Yes I have just tried your new code and still its showing 1 day ahead.
I didnt down voted your answer.